# Powerbuilder modify row columns

Tags: row, powerbuilder, protected

I have more rows. And i want for the rows with status `AA1` a column protected and for the rows with status different than `AA1` the same column unprotected. 
So I wrote this:

```
ll_count = dw_list.RowCount()
   if ll_count > 0 then 
    for i = 1 to ll_count
            if dw_list.object.status[i] = 'AA1' then
                 dw_list.modify("f_change[i].Protect='1")
                //dw_list.Object.f_change[i].modify("f_change[i].Protect='1")
                dw_list.Object.f_change[i].Background.Color = gf_get_btnface()
            end if
            if dw_list.object.status[i] <> 'AA1' then               
                dw_list.modify("f_change[i].Protect='0'")           
            end if
    next
   end if
```

But `dw_list.modify("f_change[i].Protect='1'")` is not correct. Neither `dw_list.Object.f_change[i].modify("f_change[i].Protect='1")`. 
If I just write `dw_list.modify("f_change.Protect='1'")` it modifies all the rows.

Comment: When you have rows of data displayed and wish to have different attributes for the entries in those rows based on the data within the rows/columns, a datawindow expression is usually the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woud do this without programming a single line, but by editing the datawindow design.

1. Open the datawindow in design mode
2. Select the desired column
3. In the 'General' tab, click on the small icon nearby 'Protect'.
4. Insert there the condiction to protect or not that column: `if( status = 'AA1', '0', '1')`

Done for all your data.
The same process can be applied to many characteristics of data window columns (color, background color, visible, pointer, position,...)
Alternatively, you could put the condition programmatically, but I would only do it if you need to change the protection scheme 'on the fly'.  Anyway, the principle is to set the protect condition on the column itself.
Generally speaking, try to do in PowerBuilder as much as you can WITHOUT script programming.  U

Comment: Just to add, it's important to understand that attributes like Protect can't be manipulated on a row-by-row basis. Modify() manipulates the template of the DW, so it affects all rows. The power to do what you want is when DW attributes support expressions, and most do.